# How can I specify the window size for Emacs on a Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source, emacs

I used to be able to launch [Emacs](https://emacsformacosx.com/) version 28.1 on macOS from the command line in XQuartz terminal window like so:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --geometry 109x65 &
```

After upgrading to version 29.1, the geometry option appears not to be respected any more. Instead, Emacs with a default, smaller window size appears in the background, behind the rest of the XQuartz terminal windows.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in the help page has a typo. The correct command is this (note the **single dash** instead of two dashes):

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -geometry 109x65 &
```

Help page (wrong):

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --help
...
--geometry, -g GEOMETRY         window geometry
...
```